# Why isn't 'false' equal to 'nil'?

Tags: ruby

`false` is not equal to `nil`, for example:

```
false == nil # => false
```

The same goes for `false` and `0`:

```
false == 0 # => false
```

You get the same result for `nil` and `0`:

```
nil == 0 # => false
```

Why does Ruby act like this?

Comment: why would False == nil? are apples == oranges?

Comment: Doesn't seem weird to me. They're different _types_ of things. You'll find the same kind of thing in other languages. Try `False == None` in Python or `false == null` in JavaScript. In Python `False == 0`, but that's a quirk if you ask me. And in JavaScript, `null == undefined`, but that's pretty bizarre IMO. When things of different types are considered equal, that leads to all kinds of headaches, which is why it's recommended to use `===` in JS for example.

Comment: Ruby isn't acting weird. It's per the spec. I think the expectations of what is "normal" is what's unwarranted. In Ruby, all values evaluate to *truthy* except for FALSE and nil which evaluate to *falsey*. (All of the comparisons shown in the question evaluate to false, and that is the behavior we expect, because that's whats documented in the language specification.

Comment: Your question is unclear. `fase == 0` is `false`, because `false` and `0` are not equal. They are completely different things that have absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with each other. Why *would* they be equal? It would help if you explain why you explain they should be equal, otherwise the simple answer to your question is just: "because they aren't equal, and anything else just makes no sense".

Answer (score 5):

In Ruby, the only time `nil` will return `true` on a `==` comparison is when you do: `nil == nil`

You can read more about `nil` here:

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/NilClass.html

`nil` is the equivalent of `undefined` in JavaScript  or `None` in Python

Consider in JavaScript:

```
>> (undefined === false)
=> false
```

Or Python:

```
>> (None == False)
=> False
```

Comment: @ChayHuan Glad I could help. Please consider marking the answer as correct.

Comment: Updated :) Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you for caring about our future sentient NLP engines in their attempts to learn Ruby!

Comment: @ChayHuan Probably better to wait a while for other answers before accepting. There is no rush.

Comment: @SagarPandya Which kind of other answers might there be? (Just out of curiosity, wonder what else could be covered)

Comment: I guess we'll have to wait and see. Others may point out something new or provide a different explanation which may or may not be clearer. My previous comment is by no means a slight on your answer.

Comment: no, I didnt take it like that at all. Im meant it more really curiously what else I might be able to cover, thats all :)

Comment: Pedantry: Your JavaScript example would be better with `===` as `==` can do some surprising conversions. And careful with `null` in SQL, `null = null` is not true in SQL so SQL's `null` isn't quite the same as Ruby's `nil`.

Comment: Updated - Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

### Nil and False (Equality)

Despite what many people new to the language may expect, `nil` and `false` are objects rather than language keywords. Consider [FalseClass](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/FalseClass.html) which says:

> The global value `false` is the only instance of class `FalseClass` and represents a logically false value in boolean expressions.

Likewise, [NilClass](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/NilClass.html) is:

> [t]he class of the singleton object `nil`.

When you use a method like [Comparable#==](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Comparable.html#method-i-3D-3D) to compare them, Ruby invokes the spaceship operator `<=>` on the instances since neither class defines the `#==` method. Because nil and false are not the same objects, and because neither overrides the basic equality operator, the expression `false == nil` will always be false.

Likewise, an Integer like `0` is neither an instance of FalseClass nor NilClass. Both `false == 0` and `nil == 0` are therefore also false because neither instance evaluates to zero.

### Truthy and Falsey (Conditionals)

For branching purposes, both `false` and `nil` evaluate as false in a conditional expression. Everything else evaluates as true.

Consider the following non-idiomatic, contrived, but hopefully illustrative example of Ruby's basic truth tables:

```
def truth_table value
  if value
    true
  else
    false
  end
end

truth_table nil
#=> false

truth_table false
#=> false

truth_table true
#=> true

truth_table 'a'
#=> true

truth_table 0
#=> true

truth_table 1
#=> true
```

### Boolean Evaluation

Nil and false are semantically different in Ruby, and descend from different base classes. They are also not equal to each other. However, they can both be treated as "not true" for branching purposes or within a Boolean context. For example, consider the following idioms for casting a result as a Boolean true or false value:

```
!(nil)
#=> true

!!(nil)
#=> false
```

You can use this idiom to shorten the previous truth table example to:

```
# Convert any value to a Boolean.
def truth_table value
  !!value
end

# Test our truth table again in a more compact but less readable way.
table = {}
[nil, false, true, 'a', 0, 1].map { |v| table[v] = truth_table(v) }; table
#=> {nil=>false, false=>false, true=>true, "a"=>true, 0=>true, 1=>true}
```